# How to log requests between graphQL and database?

Tags: node.js, graphql-js

I cannot find anything about this, neither from docs, here or web. I tried [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) like this:

```
app.use(morgan()) // app is just a simple express server that also uses /graphql endpoint
```

..but it only logs requests to GraphQL endpoint, *e.g* `POST /graphql 200 1.430 ms` .

---

In order to log all requests between GraphQL and database, where should I use logger or should I write something myself and where? I imagine that I shouldn't repeat myself in every `resolver`..